# SEG FAULT while assigning memory to the pointer of vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, std

```
struct LeafDataEntry   
{
    void *key;
    int a;
};


int main(){

    //I want to declare a vector of structure
    vector<LeafDataEntry> leaves;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
       leaves[i].key = (void *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
       //assign some value to leaves[i].key using memcpy
    }

}
```

I am getting SEG FAULT error for this code while doing the malloc in for loop above....Any suggestions for any alternative to assign memory to the pointer in the vector of structs.

Comment: How is the vector supposed to know it should contain 100 elements?

Comment: What is your `key` will be ultimately storing, what type of data?

Comment: @KerrekSB, Omg I love the link. It's so easy to remember now.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Funny, since it's the use of `std::vector` that causes the segfault in this case...

Comment: I am using 100 just for here...In my original code, I dont know the size beforehand...and thats why I am using vector to grow my array at run time. Else I could have used an array of fixed size.

Comment: @Anonymous yep so see my answer which will deal with that for you.

Comment: @Michael - My Key may store - Int, Real or varchar

Comment: @Anonymous - The problem is that `leaves[i]` doesn't exist. The two answers provided so far address the problem.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Well, it's not about the size of the vector, but what you put into it :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB HA HA .... dangely parts   (Harvey Birdman)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you are trying to assign to a vector which does not have the elements yet. Do this instead:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    LeafDataEntry temp;
    leaves.push_back(temp); 
    leaves[i].key = (void *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
    //assign some value to leaves[i].key using memcpy
 }
```

That way you will be accessing actual memory.

In the comments the OP mentioned that the number of elements in the array will be decided at runtime. You can set `i < someVar` which will allow you to decide `someVar` and the size of the list at runtime.

The other answer

```
leaves.resize(someVar) //before the loop
```

Is probably a better way to go though because it is likely that it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You're indexing an empty vector. Try using

```
leaves.resize(100);
```

Before the loop.